# Keras Training a CNN - Should I Convert Heatmap Data As Image or 2D Matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, data-processing

I am interested in training a Keras CNN and I have some data in the form of 2D matrices (e.g. width x height). I normally represent, or visualize the data like a heatmap, with a colorbar.

However, in training the CNN and formatting the data input, I'm wondering if I should keep this matrix as a 2D matrix, or convert it into an RGB image that is essentially a 3D matrix?

What is the best practice and some considerations people should take into account?

Comment: You need to reshape your data to have shape `(number_of_examples, width, height, channels)` in `keras` - so the data must be `3-dim`. However it's not essential to have 3 channels - you could easily have only one channel.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko aaa okay, that makes sense!

Comment: So - I formulated an answer :)

Comment: If you don't mind - I'd appreciate an upvote and accepting my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact - you need to reshape a single data point to have a `3D` shape - as `keras` expects your dataset to have shape `(number examples, width, height, channels)`. If you don't wont to make your image `RGB` - you can simply leave it with only one channel (and interpret it as `greyscale` channel).